# Complicated Analytics+Website Optimizer tracking

Tags: jquery, web, analytics, tracking, optimization

I have a sort of complicated tracking script. :-) Basically, I want to track user's click on a link (=that's a conversion). So the link has a javascript onClick event:

```
<a href='http://convertingpage.com' onClick='trackConversion(this)'>BUY NOW</a>
```

And the function contains multiple tracking scripts:

```
function trackConversion(that){
// CPC network tracking script (not important)
// another CPV network tracking script (not important)

----- HERE SHOULD COME THE GOOGLE WEBSITE OPTIMIZER SCRIPT -----

// tracking for google analytics goals (NOT website optimizer):
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/clicked.php']);
}
```

And as you maybe know, the website optimizer conversion script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['gwo._setAccount', 'UA-1234567-2']);
  _gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/2462373171/goal']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

**How would you put this script (above) into the trackConversion() function?**

I tried to remove all the *unnecessary* (I guess :-)) code and left this:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['gwo._setAccount', 'UA-1234567-2']);
  _gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/2462373171/goal']);
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

I removed the (function(){...})(); part because it seemed strange to me to have a *function inside a function*. Will this work?

By the way, when you try:

```
alert(_gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/2462373171/goal'])); // returns 2
```

in the script above, it returns the number **2**. When you comment the first line, it returns **0**:

```
//var _gaq = _gaq || [];
alert(_gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/2462373171/goal'])); // returns 0**
```

Is any of this going to work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `(function() {})();` is an anonymous function, nothing strange. If you already use Analytics on your page, you can remove all this part (it call the same tracking code).

Simply put

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['gwo._setAccount', 'UA-1234567-2']);
_gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/2462373171/goal']);
```

in your `function trackConversion()` and it should works fine !